# Not able to send log to logstash in another server using logstash-logger gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logstash

I am using rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.0. I have included the following in the environment file

```
 config.logstash = [
 {
        type: :tcp,
        port: 5044,
        host: 'log server ip addrees',
        verify_hostname: false
  }
]
```

in Gemfile

```
gem "lograge"
gem "logstash-event"
gem 'logstash-logger'
```

Then I have opened the inbound port 5044 of log server and outbound port for the app server. But is showing the error

```
[LogStashLogger::Device::TCP] Errno::EPIPE - Broken pipe
```

I have installed elk stack in log server to receive logs from stg and dev server. But currently is getting the above error.

I also have another doubt, if it succeed then how can I identify from which server(stg or prod) the log came?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by writing the log to a file. Then use an application *firebeat* to send the Json file to the logstash server. It will send the new logs to the 5044 port of logstash server which is read by the sever. In filebeat, I am setting a variable as prod, stg corresponding to each server to identify the server in logstash configuration.